# Site CSS is broken, un-visited links appear blue, alignment in user profiles is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Noticed this issue about an hour ago, [see chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22323852#22323852).

**Issue 1**
CSS issues are causing all unvisited links to appear blue until visited, at which point they go the normal redish:

[image: Image depicting incorrect css for links]

**Issue 2**
When you visit a user's profile, their page looks incorrectly aligned:
[image: Image depicting user's profile which is incorrectly aligned]

**What is going on?**

ETA: This is affecting both the main site as well as our meta.

Comment: We're assuming this is because we're being aligned to the new site CSS. But could be something else.

Comment: Oddly enough, the same thing is happening on Seasoned Advice SE.

Comment: It's been fixed ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[We have an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259186/295850)

> We rolled out a new image uploader today. Unfortunately, the design was targeted at the new-design sites only, and so the image uploader stopped working (at all) on the old-design sites.
>
> In a hurry to get the image uploader working, we grafted the new image uploader styles to the old base styles. This had some of the side effects you noticed. We have since fixed these side effects. My sincere gratitude to our design team for helping out with this in off-hours!